# Customizing PATH for .zshrc

Tags: terminal, zsh

In my user's composer folder I have 2 executables...

```
$ ls ~/.composer/vendor/bin/
envoy     homestead
```

I'm attempting to modify my `PATH` variable for oh-my-zsh so that I don't have to customize the path to this every time.

I've modified the `PATH` export so that it includes this directory, but despite having restarted my terminal I can't seem to get it to recognize the executable....

**.zshrc**

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/in:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:vendor/bin:${PATH}"
```

Notice using the full path will properly execute the program...

```
$ ~/.composer/vendor/bin/homestead
Laravel Homestead version 2.0.7

Usage:
  [options] command [arguments]
```

The file permissions of the executables are:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  group   22 Jun  2 09:14 envoy -> ../laravel/envoy/envoy
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  group   30 Nov 28 11:30 homestead -> ../laravel/homestead/homestead
```

Comment: Do they have the executable bit set?

Comment: @HBruijn I've added the permissions to my question

Comment: That's only the permission on the symlink not the target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell isn't expanding ~ in quotes. Use a full path or replace with $HOME